# Latest NDK can't find module libz

Tags: android, android-ndk

I was using NDK 13.1 before, but after I updated it to 16.1(seems the latest one), my Android project can't `libz` any more.

```

> Error:(693) Android NDK: Module pngt depends on undefined modules: z
>
> Error:(706) *** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to >allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.
>
> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':xxx'.
>   executing external native build for ndkBuild xxx/jni/Android.mk
>   ```

I did't change anything else at all, and also I can find `libz` stay in my android NDK directory correctly.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting that error, just remove libz from your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIRBARIES`. It wasn't being used before. That warnings is to tell you that it was being ignored.

Comment: doesn't `Module pngt depends on undefined modules: z` shows I need `libz`?

Comment: No, it shows that you have libz in your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`, and that it is being ignored. It has always been ignored. The new version of the NDK just tells you about it.

Comment: I don't quite understand, but I've tried to remove this dependency, but it turns out my compiling cannot finish, `pngt` actually needs some of its method.

Comment: If pngt has anything to do with png's I'm pretty sure it'll need libz, worse comes to worse just clone zlib from aosp (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/zlib.git/+/master) into your source into a dir called zlib. Then add as a module into your Android.mk file before pngt, for example I'm sure this would suffice https://hastebin.com/zudageyavi.swift

Comment: If neither my answer nor @Surge1223's answer helped, there's something about your build that at least one of the three of us isn't understanding correctly. This would be much easier to diagnose if you could share your Android.mk and the specific linking error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem, I don't know if this could help your case but since This question was the first question that came up in my searches to solve this problem, I have decided to answer it for other people that have done it wrong, the way I did:

I did this which gave me the error:
find_library(zlib libz) # wrong way
which was wrong and I had to omit the lib part of libz like this:

```
find_library(zlib z) # right way
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Android.mk :

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz

If that doesn't work, use LDFLAGS to specify the path to the libz.so

For me for ex.

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -L/opt/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64/usr/lib

Of course this is assuming that you originally had the below, which is failing now.

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libz